# Given $\sin{A}:\sin{B}:\sin{C}$ how to find $\sin{(2A)}:\sin{(2B)}:\sin{(2C)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

> Given $x,y,z>0$, and the positive number $k$ such
>   $$\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+k}+\dfrac{y^2}{y^2+k}+\dfrac{z^2}{z^2+k}=1$$
>   in $\Delta ABC$,
>   $$(1):\sin{A}:\sin{B}:\sin{C}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+k}:\dfrac{y}{y^2+k}:\dfrac{z}{z^2+k}$$
>   $$(2): \sin{(2A)}:\sin{(2B)}:\sin{(2C)}=\dfrac{1}{x^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{y^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{z^2+k}$$
>   show that: $$(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$$

this problem is from I write a paper, and this result seems interesting.

My idea:

and if $x=3,y=4,z=18$,then $$\dfrac{9}{9+k}+\dfrac{16}{16+k}+\dfrac{324}{324+k}=1,k>0$$

then
$$k=96$$see:[equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%2F%289%2Bk%29%2B16%2F%2816%2Bk%29%2B324%2F%28324%2Bk%29%3D1)

then $$\sin{A}:\sin{B}:\sin{C}=4:5:6$$
see:[2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F%289%2B96%29%3A4%2F%2816%2B96%29%3A18%2F%28324%2B96%29)
so use sine therom
$$a:b:c=4:5:6$$
let $$a=4t,b=5t,c=6t$$
so
$$\cos{A}=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\dfrac{3}{4},\cos{B}=\dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\dfrac{9}{16},\cos{C}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ac}=\dfrac{1}{8}$$

so
$$\cos{A}:\cos{B}:\cos{C}=12:9:2$$
so
$$\sin{2A}:\sin{2B}:\sin{2C}=(4\cdot 12):(5\cdot 9):(6\cdot 2)=16:15:4$$
and other hand
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{y^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{z^2+k}=\dfrac{1}{9+96}:\dfrac{1}{16+96}:\dfrac{1}{324+96}=16:15:4$$
see [3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%289%2B96%29%3A1%2F%2816%2B96%29%3A1%2F%28324%2B96%29)

**second example:**

> let $x=\sqrt{2},y=\sqrt{5},z=\sqrt{10}$,then 
>   we easy to find $k=10$ see [4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F%282%2Bk%29%2B5%2F%285%2Bk%29%2B10%2F%2810%2Bk%29%3D1),
>   and 
>   $$\sin{A}:\sin{B}:\sin{C}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{12}:\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{15}:\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{20}=5\sqrt{2}:4\sqrt{5}:3\sqrt{10}$$
>   so
>   $$\cos{B}=\dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\dfrac{50+90-80}{2\times 5\sqrt{2}\times 3\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
>   $$\cos{A}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\cos{C}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$
>   so
>   $$\sin{2A}:\sin{2B}:\sin{2C}=5:4:3$$
>   other hand
>   $$\sin{2A}:\sin{2B}:\sin{2C}=\dfrac{1}{x^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{y^2+k}:\dfrac{1}{z^2+k}=\dfrac{1}{12}:\dfrac{1}{15}
> :\dfrac{1}{20}=5:4:3$$
>   so this case is also true

But I can't prove this.can you help?

Comment: Your title is not clear: what is a konwsin (or perhaps konw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$p = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + k}, \quad q = \frac{y^2}{y^2 + k}, \quad r = \frac{z^2}{z^2 + k}.$$

Then by assumption $p + q + r = 1$.

Letting $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the sides of the triangle, we have by the sine law
$$\begin{align*}
a^2 : b^2 : c^2 &= \sin^2 A : \sin^2 B : \sin^2 C \\
&= \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + k)^2} :  \frac{y^2}{(y^2 + k)^2} : \frac{z^2}{(z^2 + k)^2} \\
&= \frac{x^2}{x^2 + k}\frac{k}{x^2 + k} : \frac{y^2}{y^2 + k}\frac{k}{y^2 + k} : \frac{z^2}{z^2 + k}\frac{k}{z^2 + k} \\
&= p(1-p):q(1-q):r(1-r) \\
&= p(q + r):q(p + r): r(p + q).
\end{align*}
$$

Now by the sine and cosine laws, we have (using the symbol $\propto$ to mean "is proportional to"),
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin 2A &= 2\sin A \cos A \\
&\propto a\frac{b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc} \\
&\propto a^2(b^2 + c^2 - a^2) \\
&\propto p(q+r)[q(p+r) + r(p+q) - p(q + r)] \\
&=2pqr(q+r) \\
&\propto q + r \\
&= 1 - p \\
&= \frac{k}{x^2 + k} \\
&\propto \frac{1}{x^2 + k}.
\end{align*}
$$